# Change inner part of website

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a website. The left and right  are same. Only the main  is change when one of the buttons is pressed. I've looked at some topics and tried this code:

```
<button id="item1">Go to topic 1</button>
<button id="item2">Another topic</button>

<div id="main"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#item1").click(function(){$("#main").load("page1.html");});
    $("#item2").click(function(){$("#main").load("page2.html");});
  });
</script>
```

The first button (item1) worked perfectly, but the second one didn't at all :(. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: This afternoon all the button worked. It may be the hosting being slow or something. Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: Does `page2.html` exist?

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: page2 does exist, no error :|

Comment: for `page1.html` and `page2.html` are they at all in a subfolder such as pages? If so then you will need `subfoldername/page1.html` also just a silly question, does page1.html and page2.html have any text inside of them? Maybe they are blank

Comment: Be more realistic !! -_- I'm not a newbie :3

Answer (score 0):

May be because you put this script inside page1.html

Comment: I put it in another html (index.html)

Answer (score 0):

After 5 hours waiting, I tested it again and it worked. It may be because of the slow hosting. Thanks for your help. :D